# In openfire XMPP, how to get notified when any room is created or destroyed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire, muc

I want to subscribe to conference.xmpp.myserver.com so that when any room is created or destroyed under conference.xmpp.myserver.com, I want my app to be notified. I am using XMPP API from iOS app. I know that I can subscribe to a room or get disco#items of any specific room if I knew the room JID. But how can I get notified if any room is created or destroyed under conference.xmpp.myserver.com?

I'll appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no functionality in XMPP or any of the XEPs to do this. Perhaps there is an Openfire-specific way.